# How to invalidate session when browser is closed in IE and Chrome - Groovy and Grails Framework

Tags: session-timeout

We have set 5 maximum concurrent session in Grails application.  Most of the time, users are closed browser without logout.  So the no of concurrent session is reaching to maximum concurrent session.  How to invalidate session during browser close

Thanks
Sivalingam thangavel.